# Add elements contained in list and map them to a string

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, iterator, concurrentmodification

### Input

> SomeName SomeFine
>
> OtherName OtherFine
>
> SomeOtherName SomeOtherFine
>
> OtherName SomeOtherFine
>
> SomeName OtherFine

### Explanation

I want to make a `List<Map<String, Integer>>` so as to create a list of names and the total fines imposed upon them

### Expected output

The output I'm expecting (with reference to the example above) is something like this:

> [SomeName=SomeFine+OtherFine, OtherName=OtherFine+SomeOtherFine, SomeOtherName=SomeOtherFine]

### Code

I tried using the following code, but it's giving me a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Here's the code:

```
public List<Map<String, Integer>> calculateTotalFine(){

        List<Map<String, Integer>> myMapList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Integer>>();

        ListIterator<CrimeInfo> crimeIterator = list.listIterator();
        while(crimeIterator.hasNext()){
            String key = crimeIterator.next().getName();
            Integer value = crimeIterator.next().getFine();

            if(myMapList.isEmpty()){
                Map<String, Integer> aMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                aMap.put(key, value);
                myMapList.add(aMap);
            }

            else{
                Iterator<Map<String, Integer>> mapIterator = myMapList.iterator();
                while(mapIterator.hasNext()){
                    if(mapIterator.next().containsKey(key)){  //<-- Line no. 29
                        Integer newFine = mapIterator.next().get(key) + value;
                        mapIterator.remove();

                        Map<String, Integer> nMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                        nMap.put(key, newFine);
                        myMapList.add(nMap);
                    }
                    else{
                        Map<String, Integer> newMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                        newMap.put(key, value);
                        myMapList.add(newMap);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return myMapList;
    }
```

### Actual output

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>       at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
>       at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
>       at com.company.CoreLogic.calculateTotalFine(CoreLogic.java:29)

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `ConcurrentModificationException` can be thrown when iterating too quickly because Collections are fail-fast

Comment: @ifly So should I use the Iterator from `java.util.concurrent`?

Comment: @ifly6: No, that "too quickly" is entirely bogus. `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown if you modify a collection while iterating over it, whether that modification is performed in a different thread or the same thread. It's nothing to do with "iterating too quickly".

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] for this so we can reproduce it easily.

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong here, for example, you're calling `next()` more then once in the same iteration on the same `Iterator`, you're adding elements to a `Collection` while you iterate it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're iterating over `myMapList`, but modifying it while you're iterating:

```
myMapList.add(newMap);
```

I still haven't quite got to grips with what you're trying to do, but fundamentally you shouldn't be adding to the collection while you're iterating over it. One common approach is to create a *new* collection which you modify while you're iterating, and then (if necessary) perform a bulk modification of the original collection afterwards.

(As Titus says, you're also calling `next()` twice within your loop... you need to take more care over how you use your iterators, and use an enhanced-for loop where possible.)